# Make a C# program be able to compile on any operating system

Tags: c#, operating-system, badimageformatexception, initializecomponent

I have started making a C# program on a XP 32bit windows operating system in c# 2008, and now i am trying to open it in Windows 7 64bit operating system. The problem that arises is that i can't run the program in c# 2010 on my 64bit system and it won't go past the Initialize Component(); line in my code. It comes up with an error of, "BadImageFormatException was unhandled" which i think is because of the system change of where i am opening it. Any help on this we be brilliant.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are faced with is that you have compiled the app with Any CPU.  Change it to x86 and recompile.

Most likely you have a library you are dependent on which is x86.  Because your app is compiled as Any CPU, the Win7 x64 system is loading it as a 64bit app... and failing when trying to load the 32 bit library.

Comment: I go to this but it gives me only one option of "AnyCPU" so i can't change it to any other like "x86"?

Comment: @Chris, look at "Platform target" rather than at "Platform". In VS2008, the former gives you multiple options, but not the latter.

Comment: @RoadWarrior: Although, one should note that Debug and Release store these separately, so you'll likely want to change both.

Answer (score 1):

In Build->Configuration Manager, is your Platform set to "Any CPU" for each project?

Comment: Note that it's not "Platform", it's "Platform target".

Answer (score 0):

What is your build profile set to AnyCPU, x86, or x64 there is of course compiling the program on the new machine.

I assume you have all the updates to .NET and Visual Studio on each computer, correct?

Comment: I think i set it to AnyCPU, also i am on my laptop at home, windows 7 64bit, and can't get to the 32bit xp computer, so need to change it on my windows 7 64bit system using c# 2010

Comment: You should be able to recompile the project. Some additional information: http://dobrzanski.net/2010/06/29/attempt-load-program-incorrect-format-exception-hresult-0x8007000b/ this was posted by http://stackoverflow.com/users/118896/jaroslaw-dobrzanski